# Conditional search, match and replace values between data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have two dataframes as shown below. I would like to replace text (cells) in dataframe 1 with corresponding values taken from dataframe 2 when there is a match. I have tried to give a simple example below.
I have some limited experience with R but cant think of an easy solution right away. Any help/suggestions will be much appreciated.

```
input_1 = data.frame(col1 = c("ex1", "ex2", "ex3", "ex4"), 
                     col2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                     col3 = c("B", "E", "F", "D"))

input_2 = data.frame(colx = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 
                coly = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))

output = data.frame(col1 = c("ex1", "ex2", "ex3", "ex4"), 
                    col2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                    col3 = c(2, 5, 6, 4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a *tidyverse* solution :

```
library(tidyverse)
mutate_at(input_1, -1, ~deframe(input_2)[as.character(.)])
#   col1 col2 col3
# 1  ex1    1    2
# 2  ex2    2    5
# 3  ex3    3    6
# 4  ex4    4    4
```

`deframe` builds a named vector from a data frame, more convenient in this case.

`as.character` is necessary as you have factor columns

Answer (score 1):

Example using tidyverse. My solution involved merging twice to input_2, but matching different columns. The last pipe cleans the data frame and renames the columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

input_1 = data.frame(col1 = c("ex1", "ex2", "ex3", "ex4"), 
                     col2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                     col3 = c("B", "E", "F", "D"))

input_2 = data.frame(colx = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), 
                coly = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))


output = data.frame(col1 = c("ex1", "ex2", "ex3", "ex4"), 
                    col2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                    col3 = c(2, 5, 6, 4))


input_1 %>% inner_join(input_2, by = c("col2" = "colx")) %>%
    inner_join(input_2, by = c("col3" = "colx")) %>% 
    select(col1, coly.x, coly.y) %>%
    magrittr::set_colnames(c("col1", "col2", "col3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach using base R would be to loop over columns where we want to change values using `lapply`, `match` the values with `input_2$colx` and get the corresponding `coly` value.

```
input_1[-1] <- lapply(input_1[-1], function(x) input_2$coly[match(x, input_2$colx)])

input_1
#  col1 col2 col3
#1  ex1    1    2
#2  ex2    2    5
#3  ex3    3    6
#4  ex4    4    4
```

Actually, you could go away without using `lapply`, you could directly `unlist` the values and `match`

```
input_1[-1] <- input_2$coly[match(unlist(input_1[-1]), input_2$colx)]
```